# Spring Microservices Communication inside maven pom

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on spring based application and I am using `xml` based configuration. Now the problem is I have to maven modules like `app-web` and `app-db`. I need to make a communication b\w them. I have already Introduced `app-db` as dependency but I am struggling to introduce it inside `spring-bean.xml`. I am able to configure them using `java based configuration` but having problem using xml based configuration.

Please Note that `app-db` is hibernate based and and therefore `spring-config.xml` is inside `resources/META-INF/spring/spring-config.xml`. Can you please look at below configurations and guide me to communicate them.

`spring-config.xml` for web module

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web,com.db" />
```

**app-db** configuration, path: `resources/META-INF/spring/spring.config.xml`

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.db" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.db.dao" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="postgres" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="defaultReadOnly" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpaData" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect" />
                <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
        proxy-target-class="true" />
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what do mean by 'but I am struggling to introduce it inside spring-bean.xml', what is your issue. 1) you are not able to access beans from app-db in app-web or anything else

Comment: @Yogi yes, I am not able to access beans of app-db inside app-web

Answer (score 0):

If You are using component scan via Spring configuration class, you can do it like:

```
 @Configuration
    @EntityScan("com.web","com.db")
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.db")
    public class EmbeddedConfigurationA {
    }
```

If you want to do it via XML config:

You need to import configuration using below command

```
<import resource="classpath*:spring-config.xml" />
```

Scan bans from package:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com">
   <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="(db|web)\..*"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

OR

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.db, com.web" />
```